# Unable to reopen the closed popup window and unable to add close code for close button in it - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, popupwindow

The below popup window works when click for First time but then it does not open again, may be the session is still running in back end. Added a close button in the popup window, was able to add the button but unable to add the code to close the active popup window. Please assist

```
<script>
var previewML;
function previewML() {
previewML = window.open("", "previewML", "width=600, height=800, scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");
previewML.document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + document.getElementById("Manlogs").value + '<pre>' + <button type="button" onclick="closeML()">Close</Button>';
}

function closeML() {
  previewML.close();   // Closes the new window
}
</script>

GR/DR LOGS:
<img src="GRZoom.png" onmouseover="this.src='GRZoom1.png';" onmouseout="this.src='GRZoom.png';" onclick="previewML()" style="float: right;" width="25" height="25" id="preview" title="Click to Zoom/Preview logs"/>
<textarea class="form-control taAfLogs" id="AFlogs"></textarea>
```

Comment: `closeML` is on the opener page, you've to call `opener.closeML()`. The opening problem is due to the fact that you're overwriting the function with the window, hence you can't call the function again. Rename the function or the popup.

Comment: @Teemu : It closes the active popup window, but I am unable to reopen the popup window, have to refresh the webpage to make it work again

Comment: Did you rename the function, and also called the function with the new name?

Comment: @Teemu, Which function should I rename brother

Comment: Please re-read my first comment.